# embedded mongo + spring configuration unit tests fail en masse (failed to load application context)

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-data, embedded-database

I'm not sure if this is a embedded mongo issue or a a spring configuration issue, maybe someone else has had the same problem.

I have a spring+maven project set up in Intellij, and have embedded mongo in test scope.

**The problem:** When I right click on the test java folder to run all tests, I get the dreaded application context error (see below for details). However running tests individually, or even package by package is fine. I have discovered that there is 1 test (coincidentally the first one that runs in the entire set) that is causing the break, and if I delete it I can run all tests again. Let's call this `TestA`. I'd like to understand why this one test causes all others to fail, and how to fix it (Since i'd really like to have that test!).

All tests extend a base class that starts with this (**except** for `TestA`):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Config.class, MongoConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("${port}")
@Component
```

`TestA` is slightly different because it doesn't need Mongo to run, but does need spring to autowire the services. I thought this would be ok, but it's not:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
@Component
```

`MongoConfig.class` is simply annotated:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "<my package>")
```

plus the `@Bean`s for creating the mongo process.

`Config.class` has these annotations and en empty body:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(value = {<list of packages>})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"my package"})
```

However if i try to run *all* the tests they all fail with the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 <huge stack trace eventually ending with...>
 Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Temp\extract-john-extractmongod.exe
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:124)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)
at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.extract.ExtractedFileSets.copy(ExtractedFileSets.java:54)
at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ExtractedArtifactStore.extractFileSet(ExtractedArtifactStore.java:110)
at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Starter.prepare(Starter.java:56)
... 192 more
```

My understanding is that somehow by adding `TestA` embedded mongo is trying to start up every time?

My temporary solution is to delete the annotations in `TestA` and extend the base class described above. That makes it all work fine, but isn't really correct. What I need is the right annotations on `TestA` for it to work in tandem with the rest of the tests.

**dependencies**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.50.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**spring configuration**

I don't use xml files, rather I set up class Configuration files tied up with yml files (facets added to module in Intellij).

Comment: Why is your test an `@Component` and also your `SpringApplicationConfiguration` should point to your application class. You end up with 2 contexts probably influencing one another. You seem also to be working around spring boot which might even cause your issue.

Comment: As @M.Deinum mentioned: SpringApplicationConfiguration creates a second context. Looks like, each context creation starts the embedded mongod but you can only start one.

Comment: Docs for SpringApplicationConfiguration reads "Class-level annotation that is used to determine how to load and configure an ApplicationContext for integration tests." I suggest you use the same annotation for all the tests.